# GLSL: x * 0.0 != 0.0

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm trying to do normal mapping in my fragment shader which causes rendering issues. I've boiled down the problem to the following:

I have my normal vector n and tangent t. If I do:

```
return n;
```

It all works fine and dandy (but obviously not normal mapped). However, if I do:

```
return n + 0.0 * t;
```

It screws everything up. To me, these seem like they should be the same thing, but apparently they're not.

```
return n + vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
```

Works fine, so obviously the issue is that:

```
0.0 * t != vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

The only case I can think of where this can happen is if x, y, or z in b is infinity. However, that's not the case as:
A:

```
0.0 * vec3(1.0/0.0, 1.0/0.0, 1.0/0.0)
```

works fine, and
B:
I've checked if it is inifinity using isinf(), which returns false.

I've also checked my code for any instance where the tangent could possibly be infinity (when normalized) but removing normalization doesn't fix it. I've also checked so the length of all tangent vectors are 1 and they are so it shouldn't be a problem either way.

Edit: I wasn't aware of the NaN possibility before so now that I've checked that and confirmed that that's indeed the case I now know the problem isn't with my GLSL code but somewhere in my OBJ model importing code. I guess this question can be marked as solved now?

Comment: `1.0/0.0` is not infinite. It is NaN.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. For me multiplying every vector by 0.0 results in a zero length vector. Maybe there's something else wrong in the shader?

Comment: Is t NaN?  We need to see *that* to decide what's going on.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware of isnan. It is indeed NaN, so now I have something to go on. Now I just need to figure out why it's NaN.     
@BDL: Pretty sure 1.0/0.0 is INF, though. If that was NaN then surely it would produce the same error?  

In what situations would a NaN occur?

Comment: The results are undefined but it won't crash the GPU (so you should avoid these cases, by clamping denominators that might be 0 and such)